# How to mock global library method (in class)?

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, moq

I would like to mock a global method in my class, I've hit a wall.

Here is basic code structure:

```cs
public sealed class Wisher : IWisher {

  private readonly int _valueA;
  private readonly int _valueB;

  public Wisher(int a){
    _valueA = a;
  }

  public Wisher(int b){
    _valueB = b;
  }

  public int myMethod(int c){

     var client = SomeHTTPFactory(c); // Like to mock this client

     var h; 

     if (_valueA != null){
       h = client.runA(a); // point A
     }
     else if (_valueB != null){
      h = client.runB(b); // point B
     }
     else {
      h = 0;
     }
     
     return h;
  }

}
```

In my moq, I would like to inject my own client to test the logic of the flow.

At core, I want to test the control flow, if `_valueA` is present point A should be invoked, and `_valueB` is present point B should be invoked. I already have mock of `SomeHTTPFactory` to ensure it always returns a value that I expect.

I'm not sure how to go about injecting `Mock<SomeHTTPFactory>` in my test of Wisher.

Any help or documentation around this pattern is appreciated.

Comment: Moq can't help you test code that is written in an untestable fashion. Provide the client factory via parameterization.

Comment: Show the code of `SomeHTTPFactory`. You could update your code to use a wrapper class instead of going full-bore DI.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to refactor your class to use dependency injection -- in the constructor of your class providing an interface to replace your "SomeHTTPFactory".  That way you'll be able to mock the item.